Clarify on the behaviour of various cohomologies for $n\gt 0$
Let $(\mathsf C,\tau)$ be a site, and let $i:\sf P \to S$ be the inclusion functor from the category of abelian presheaves $\sf P$ into the category of abelian sheaves $\sf S$ on $(\mathsf C,\tau)$. In the following, let $U$ be a fixed object in $\sf C$ and let the functor $\Gamma_U:\sf S\to Ab$  be defined on the objects (sheaves) by $\Gamma_U(F)=F(U)$.
Given a covering $\mathcal U=\{U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$, any presheaf $F$ in $\sf P$ induces the well known homomorphisms below. $$F(U)\xrightarrow{\alpha_F} \prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)\xrightarrow{\beta_F}\prod_{i,j\in I}F(U_i\times_UU_j)$$
The functor $H^0(\mathcal U,-):\sf P\to Ab$ is then defined on the objects (presheaves) as $H^0(\mathcal U,F)=\operatorname{ker}\beta_F$, and for any $n\gt 0$ one sets $H^n(\mathcal U,-)=R^n(H^0(\mathcal U,-))$.
Let $\mathsf J_U$ be the category whose objects are the coverings of $U$ and whose morphisms are the refinement maps. For any presheaf $F$ in $\sf P$ and any $n\gt 0$ there is a functor $F^n_*:\mathsf J_U^{op}\to \sf Ab$ defined on objects (coverings) by $F^n_*(\mathcal U)=H^n(\mathcal U,F)$. Then one defines the functor $\check{H^n}(U,-):\sf P\to Ab$ on the objects (presheaves) by $\check{H^n}(U,F)=\mathrm{colim}(F^n_*)$.
Finally the functor $H^n(U,-):\sf S\to Ab$ is defined, for any $n\gt 0$, as $R^n(\Gamma_U)$.
Question. It is clear that, for any covering $\mathcal U$ of $U$, one has $H^0(\mathcal U,-)\circ i=\check{H^0}(U,-)\circ i = \Gamma$. But is it true that either $H^n(\mathcal U,-)\circ i=\check{H^n}(U,-)\circ i $ or $\check{H^n}(U,-)\circ i = H^n(U,-)$ or $H^n(\mathcal U,-)\circ i = H^n(U,-)$ for $n\gt 0$?

What are your thoughts? I would apply the Grothendieck spectral sequence to $\Gamma_U \circ i$.

@MartinBrandenburg The question came to my mind after looking at 3.4.4 in Tamme indeed. Here are considered two spectral sequences associated to a sheaf $F$ in $\sf S$: one with terms $H^p(\mathcal U, R^qi(F))$ and one with terms $\check{H^p}(U, R^qi(F))$. However I would have said that at least the equality ($$) $H^p(\mathcal U,-)\circ i=\check{H^p}(U,-)\circ i$ was true, because if two functors coincide on a subcategory I don't see how their derived do not coincide on the subcategory. But if ($$) held then the two spectral sequences associated to $F$ would have equal terms from the start

Now that I think with a fresher mind maybe the error in my argument is that $R^qi(F)$ is not necessarily a sheaf if $F$ is?
